# Django execute block tag inside 'if' statement in template only if 'if' statement is true

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to execute a block tag only if an if statement is true. Here is what I mean. This is my template:

```
{% extends "homePageBase.html" %}

{% if not blogPage %}
    {% block isBlogFalse %} notBlogPage {% endblock %}
{% else %}
    {% block isBlogTrue %} blogPage {% endblock %}
{% endif %}
```

But both the block tags get executed. Is there any way for the block tags to only get executed if the if / else statements are true? Any way around this issue or any way of accomplishing this task?

Comment: are you sure both block tags get executed? I think it should not

Comment: @eagertoLearn both tags do get executed, as explained in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15434017/nested-block-statement-runs-independent-of-if-statement-validity-dja/15434114#15434114

Comment: What happens if you swap things around and do "if blogPage" instead of "if not blogPage?"

Comment: @souldeux same thing, both block tags get executed I think even before the if and else statements are read.

Answer (score 2):

One answer to the problem can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/a/18638131/573392. To modify it for your situation, it would look like:

```
{% extends blogPage|yesno:"blogPage.html,notBlogPage.html" %}
```

This solution will allow you to load a template that is dependent on the `blogPage` variable, effectively achieving the outcome of the if statement.

Comment: right, I am aware of that. However, I am wondering if there is any way to work around it? Any way to accomplish it?

Comment: hm, im not sure how that solution works for this issue. Is it possible if you can explain it? Because the solution on the post which you linked talks about extended from a different web page. How does that solve the issue which I currently have?

Comment: I just read your update. What I am looking for is to modify a block if an 'if' statement is true. If the 'if' statement is false, then I want to modify a different block. The solution you provided basically extends a template if the 'if' statement is true / false. I don't want to extend a any template regardless of what the 'if' statement evaluates to, I want to modify a block tag depending on what the 'if' statement evaluates to.. You get what I mean?